# VBA code to clearcontents in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I just need  help to clear the contents of the cells (L,M) if the value in Column B is blank (i.e. customer is the same as the previous non-blank row) and if they are duplicates in column L for each customer.

For example:

```
       Customer (B)             Sales (L)    Description (M)
row1   James                     Laptop     Laptop sold
row2                             Laptop     Laptop sold
row3                            Iphone      Iphone sold
row4   Brian                    Iphone      Iphone sold
row5                             Mouse      Mouse sold
row6                             Iphone     Iphone sold
```

Desired results:

```
       Customer (B)             Sales (L)    Description (M)
row1   James                     Laptop     Laptop sold
row2                             
row3                            Iphone      Iphone sold     
row4   Brian                    Iphone      Iphone sold
row5                             Mouse      Mouse sold
row6
```

Comment: What have you tried? This is a pretty simple VBA loop.  Do you want to keep the row, or delete it when column B is blank?

Comment: Will the duplicate always be the one in the row with the name or can there be two of the same thing without the name so for Brian would there be two Mouse, or only the Iphone because that is the one with Brian in the same row?

Comment: Please check out @Tom answer. It gives you exactly what you desire. "Don't forget to tip your waiter by clicking on the check mark next to the answer if that is useful."

Answer (score 2):

What it seems like you want is to clear the `range(E:F)` where B is blank and `range(E:F)` is the same as the row above? If this is the case you will need something like this:

```
Sub Testing2()
    Dim x
    For Each c In Range(Range("E1"), Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        If Range("B" & c.row).Value <> "" Then
            x = 1
            Do Until Range("B" & c.row + x).Value <> "" And c.row + x < Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
                Range("E" & c.row).Select
                If Range("E" & c.row).Value = Range("E" & c.row + x).Value And Range("F" & c.row).Value = Range("F" & c.row + x).Value Then
                    Range("E" & c.row + x & ":F" & c.row + x).ClearContents
                End If
                If c.row + x >= Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                x = x + 1
            Loop
        End If
        If Range("B" & c.row).Value = "" Then
            x = 1
            Do Until Range("B" & c.row + x).Value <> "" And c.row + x < Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
                Range("E" & c.row).Select
                If Range("E" & c.row).Value = Range("E" & c.row + x).Value And Range("F" & c.row).Value = Range("F" & c.row + x).Value Then
                    Range("E" & c.row + x & ":F" & c.row + x).ClearContents
                End If
                If c.row + x >= Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row Then
                    Exit Do
                End If
                x = x + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This will start at the top and work it's way down looking for duplicates for each person.

Or you could delete the row with something like this:

```
Sub Testing2()
    Dim x
    For Each c In Range(Range("E1"), Range("E" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
        If Range("B" & c.row).Value <> "" Then
            x = 1
            Do Until Range("B" & c.row + x).Value <> ""
                If Range("E" & c.row).Value = Range("E" & c.row + x).Value And Range("F" & c.row).Value = Range("F" & c.row + x).Value Then
                    Range("A" & c.row + x).Select
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
                    Selection.Delete shift:=xlUp
                End If
                x = x + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not remove row 6 as the duplicate is two rows up not one.

Comment: Please notice at @ScottCraner comment. Your code does not resolve the issue sufficiently.

Comment: That is not what I said,  Look at the data before and after Row 6 is cleared, and not because it equaled the line above but the line 2 lines above your code only looks to the line above.

Comment: @ScottCraner I see what you are saying. I've edited the code to take care of that.

Comment: Closer, as it does work on the given data so I upvoted for that, but again this makes an assumption that the only duplicate the OP cares about is the one that needs to be cleared(see my comment under the Original Post), this may be what the OP wants,  But good job.  I hope it is what the OP wants.

Comment: @ScottCraner I didn't catch that as the sample didn't have any other duplicates but what was next to the name. I have updated my code again. I also found that I'd created an infinite loop which I also fixed. Thanks apparently Friday is sleep day.

Answer (score 1):

**Update after @Masoud Comments**
This matches the output desired

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, rCell As Range
    Dim temp As Range

    ' Update this to reference your sheet
    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    For Each rCell In rng
        Set c = Nothing
        If rCell.Offset(0, 1) = vbNullString Then
            With rCell.Offset(0, 1)
                Set temp = Range(.End(xlUp), .End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Offset(0, 3)
            End With
            Set c = temp.Find(rCell.Offset(0, 4), lookat:=xlWhole, after:=rCell.Offset(0, 4))

            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                If rCell.Offset(0, 5) = c.Offset(0, 1) And c.Row <> rCell.Row Then
                    Range(rCell.Offset(0, 4), rCell.Offset(0, 5)).ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Have a look at the below. This loops through all the rows in the sheet and if the cell in Column B is blank tries to find if it is present elsewhere in the sheet. If so it then clears the contents of that row.

I think you need to define a bit more what you consider a duplicate though. As in your question you:

- leave row3 (duplicate of row6)
- remove row2 (not a duplicate unless you ignore Customer)

So you have a break in your logic. If you're comparing customers (i.e. leaving Row3) then only row6 should end up being removed. However, if you aren't comparing customers as well as part of the duplicates then row3 should also be removed from the desired results.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RemoveDuplicates()
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, rCell As Range

    ' Update this to reference your sheet
    With Sheet1
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    For Each rCell In rng
        Set c = Nothing
        If rCell.Offset(0, 1) = vbNullString Then
            Set c = rng.Offset(0, 4).Find(rCell.Offset(0, 4), lookat:=xlWhole, after:=rCell.Offset(0, 4))

            If Not c Is Nothing Then
                '' If not including customer in comparison
                If rCell.Offset(0, 5) = c.Offset(0, 1) And c.Row <> rCell.Row Then
                '' Uncomment below and comment above if comparing customers as well
                'If rCell.Offset(0, 5) = c.Offset(0, 1) And rCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = c.Offset(0, -3).Value And c.Row <> rCell.Row Then

                    Range(rCell.Offset(0, 4), rCell.Offset(0, 5)).ClearContents
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next rCell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be good to add some description and comments to it as well.

Comment: You're right but it's end of the week and I'm being lazy. As you called me on it though I will update now

Comment: Let me answer your question. As long as the customer column has not been updated, it is still considered to be the customer in the first row (e.g. row 1 to 3 are for James). We are trying to find duplicates for each customer. Your code doesn't work sufficiently now but your approach is really good.

Comment: Have a look at my comments. I think his logic isn't quite right. Tested on his data and it works according to what I think the logic should be. The output isn't logical.

Comment: I just edited my comment to answer your question. I agree that it is a little bit vague but that's what he means as I had the same problem before. (p.s. solved it in r instead of vba)

Comment: Ah ok I understand now

Comment: @Masoud I've updated my answer with all 3 options. The updated part should output how you explained it

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Tom. If I were you, I would put the final answer at the top. Have a lazy weekend and following productive days.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? I cannot get it to do anything? I created a new workbook to test this in and it doesn't remove or clear anything.

Comment: I'll try again Monday

Comment: I found part of why I couldn't get this to work `.Cells(2, 1)` is referencing cell `A2` while the example data starts in cell `B2`, as long as you assume that there are headers. Once I changed that to `.Cells(2, 2)` it found the first duplicate but only cleared the data from column `F2` and not from `E2`. I copied the code straight out to a new workbook and added the data based on the OP's example. Am I missing something?

Comment: Column A contains ID values i.e. 'row1, row2' etc. By moving the range over 1 Column you need to change the offset values

Comment: I'll try adding in the `row1` `row2` and see if that works then. I didn't add them because the OP doesn't mention them they seemed to be put in the example data to detail what the different rows were.

Comment: That did work much better. One thing you could add is the ability to remove the whole row and not just clear the two cells. I don't know if the OP wants that, but it would make more sense to me. Thanks for helping me understand what was happening in your code. I always enjoy learning.

Comment: You could do this by replacing `Range(rCell.Offset(0, 4), rCell.Offset(0, 5)).ClearContents` with `rCell.EntireRow.Delete` However this could mess up the for loop as it's not running backwards so that would need to be handled as well. No problem

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to loop over the cells, you may try something like below...

```
Sub ClearDuplicateItems()
    Dim lr As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    lr = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Columns("G:H").Insert
    Range("G2:G" & lr).Formula = "=INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH(""zzz"",B$2:B2))"
    Range("H2:H" & lr).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS(G$2:G2,INDEX(B$2:B2,MATCH(""zzz"",B$2:B2)),E$2:E2,E2)>1,NA(),"""")"
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("H2:H" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Offset(0, -2).ClearContents
    Range("H2:H" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Offset(0, -3).ClearContents
    Columns("G:H").Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```